# javascript express to postgresql

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a restaurant like web page where I have to take the clients order into a cart and submit it to the server which then sends it to the database. My problem is that once I get the input from the user, I can't seem to figure out how to get access to it from the server and send it to the database, here is my implementation of it:

this is the client side javascript/jquery:

```
var cart = [];

$('.add-to-cart').on("click", function() {
var foodItemId = $(this).closest(".food-item").data("food-item-id");
var foodName = $(this).closest(".food-item").find(".title").text();

cart.push({foodItemId: foodItemId, foodName: foodName});

renderCartItems();

});

$('.place-order').on("click", function () {
$.ajax({
  method: "post",
  url: "/sendOrder",
  data: JSON.stringify(cart),
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(i) {

  }
});

});

function renderCartItems() {
$(".cart-items").empty('');
$(cart).each(function(k, cartItem) {

  $('.cart-items').append(
   "<div  class=\"cart-item hidden\"><h5 class=\"title\">" + cartItem.foodName + "</h5><div class=\"quantity\"><span class=\"label\">x</span><span class=\"quantity number\">0</span></div>"

  );
});
if(cart.length >= 1) $('.place-order').show();
};

});
```

here is the express side:

```
app.post("/sendOrder", (req, res) => {

let orderId = req.body; //i dont know how to get the data from the ajax
let order = { order_id: orderId};
renderOrder.insert(order);
});
```

this is being imported from another file, not that many issues here but still I could use some input on how to make it better,

```
insert: (data) =>{
knex.insert({'order_id': data.order_id       }).into('order_dessert_item').asCallback(function (err, result){
  if (err) return console.log(err);
  console.log(result)
})
}
```

Comment: If I'm not wrong you want to pass data to express postgress and get the response back req.body is where you will get data being sent from frontend you can do a console.log to see that and as your insert is asynch you need to pass res as renderOrder.insert(order,res); and inseide inser fun insert : (data,res) and when successfull return as res.send("data u need to pass back to client")

Comment: yea i need to know how i can get the info from the ajax to the server and then to the database